# Type Mismatch error in VBA with a boolean variable

Tags: excel, vba, boolean, vb-like-operator

I'm trying to go through a range and check the names of the cells against a string "QUERIED", and if this comparison is false to put the value of the cell somewhere else. Excel is giving me a type mismatch error on the word False in the If statement below. I can't for the life of me see why. nameCheck is a Boolean variable.

```
Do
    namecheckCell = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(namecheckRow, 6)
    nameCheck = True
    nameCheck = namecheckCell.Name Like "QUERIED"
    MsgBox (nameCheck)
    If nameCheck Is False Then
        Sheets("List Results").Cells(namefoundCount, 1).Value = namecheckCell.Value
        namefoundCount = namefoundCount + 1
    End If
    namecheckRow = namecheckRow + 1
Loop While Not namecheckCell.Value Is Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `=` instead of `Is`, or better yet:

```
If Not nameCheck Then
```

The `Is` operator is used to compare object references, whereas `=` is used to compare value types (booleans, integers, etc.).